# Getting "Realm didn't match redirect_uri/origin. Error code: 2"

Tags: openid, google-api-java-client, openid-connect, google-openid

When I try sign in, the login window pops up as expected but it gives me this error.

```
Error: invalid_request
Realm didn't match redirect_uri/origin. Error code: 2

Request Details:

openid.realm=localhost:8080/oauth2callback
scope=email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
response_type=permission
redirect_uri=storagerelay://http/localhost:8080?id=auth435566
ss_domain=http://localhost:8080
client_id=SOME_STRING_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com
fetch_basic_profile=true
```

I read through the [Open ID 2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration#update-to-plus) and from my understanding of it, the property `openid.realm`, should be the same as one of my redirect uri's.

Here are my "Authorized redirect URIs" from the developer console in the credentials section:

```
https://myapp-1234.appspot.com/oauth2callback
http://myapp-1234.appspot.com/oauth2callback
http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback
```

I set `openid.realm` to `localhost:8080/oauth2callback` because at the moment I'm only testing my application but I have tried the other ones in deployment and I still got the same result but with different error codes.

Here is where I invoke the `signIn()` method:

```
var authConfig = {
    client_id: 'SOME_STRING_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email profile',
    openid_realm: 'localhost:8080/oauth2callback'
}

window.handleGoogleClientLoad = function () {
gapi.client.load('myapp_endpoints', 'v1', null, '//' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api');
console.log('API LOADED');
}

//=====================================================================================

function authorizeUser() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        gapi.auth2.init(authConfig)
            .then(function() {
                var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                var user = auth2.signIn();
                console.log(user);
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {
    login: authorizeUser
}
```

Here is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="lib/vendors.js"></script>
    <script src="build/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am encountering the same issue.

Comment: @Jason Malcolm Apologies for the delayed reply. But I just added an answer to this problem so check it out. Hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the wrong Google APIs library. I was using the library that you get from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis). I then imported the module.

```
import GoogleApis from 'googleapis'
```

What I was meant to do instead was use the library that can be downloaded from their own [website](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/). [Integrating](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) this is handy enough. All you have to do is add the line of code below to your `index.html`.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

The file should then look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to MyApp</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="lib/vendors.js"></script>
    <script src="build/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init" async defer></script> 
    <!-- init is the function that will get invoked when the page loads. -->
</body>
```

I then changed around my javascript. You can find references of these changes from their [code examples](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people).

```
const authConfig = {
    client_id: 'my_app.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email profile',
    fetch_basic_profile: true
}

window.init = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init(authConfig);
        auth2.signIn().then(function() {
            if(auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
                var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();

                console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
                console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
                console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

openid.realm=response_type=permission.

id_token

redirect_uri=storagerelay://https/www.zillow.com?id=auth807591
ss_domain=https://www.zillow.com

client_id=238648973530.apps.googleusercontent.com

fetch_basic_profile=true

gsiwebsdk=

access_type=online

scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid

Comment: Could you please add some words of explanation to your answer.